# Как сделать чтобы при регистрации пользователя django давал статус персонала

Tags: django

У меня на сайте есть возможность регистрации, она проходит успешно, но при попытке войти в админ-панел  выдает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы джанго сам давал статус хотябы персонала?

Views -

```
def registerView(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('login_url')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()        
return render(request,'registration/register.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: `new_user = form.save(commit=False);new_user.is_staff=True;new_user.save()` - вот так примерно

Comment: Как я понимаю это все должно выгледить так:.   def registerView(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save(commit=False).                
        new_user.is_staff=True              new_user.save()
        return redirect('login_url')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()        
return render(request,'registration/register.html',{'form':form})

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: что значит не работает? Код нерабочий или в админку не пускает?

Comment: Вероятно, нужно ещё добавить `is_active=True`

Comment: Выдает ошибку типо new_user = form.save(commit=False) is not defined,как-то так